# How \Deleted flag can be unset for all mails in cyrus-imapd mailbox?

Tags: email, email-server, imap, cyrus

I have a 5GB mailbox which I moved using imapsync. But somehow I
messed up with --delete/--delete2 option and end up with almost all the messages
having \Deleted flag set. I do not have [delayed expunge](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~dpc22/cyrus/two_phase_expunge.html) enabled, so
I can not use [unexpunge](http://linux.die.net/man/8/unexpunge) utility.  I am using cyrus-imapd v2.3.7.
Using cyrus-imapd's debugging feature I found out that email client(Roundcube in my case) fires following IMAP command to unset it.

`UID STORE 179 -FLAGS.SILENT (\Deleted)`

I don't know if somehow I can fire this command for all the mails.

Is there any way I can unset \Deleted flag for all the mails in the mailbox?

**UPDATE**:

Using @geekosaur's tip of specifying range of message-ids in the above command, I could solve it for one mailbox under INBOX like INBOX.folder1. Is there any way I can do it for multiple mailboxes under INBOX recursively? Now I am working on solving it using/creating some script, maybe using Perl's IMAP related module. But still I need to solve it asap so inputs are welcome.

**UPDATE**:

Thanks to geekosaur, I succeeded in solving it using Perl's IMAPClient module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a range of messages `start:end` in place of the single message number (`179` in your example); use `SEARCH ALL` to find out the valid message number range.

Note, this is assuming you can use raw IMAP, which can be painful to impossible if it is (as it should be) using `AUTHENTICATE` instead of `LOGIN`..  You may prefer to find an IMAP toolkit of some kind (note that Cyrus `imapd` comes with Perl libraries that can be used to script logging in and performing various operations, although you will need to have some familiarity with RFC 2060.

Comment: thanks a lot, you have saved my day. By specifying range I could solve it for one of the mailbox under INBOX. I have multiple mailboxes under INBOX like INBOX.folder1, INBOX.folder2 etc. Is there any way to use this functionality recursively?

Comment: Not with the standard IMAP protocol; you need to `SELECT` each folder individually.

Comment: thanks for your tips. I have started working on it. Still I am keeping the question open for some time.

Comment: Unfortunately, as presently designed the protocol doesn't really support multifolder operations (note how the notion of current folder is built into the protocol, and how hierarchy is kinda hacked in with various special flags in `LIST` etc.). IMAP is overdue for a redesign for better multifolder support, but various proposed extensions for it have languished.

Comment: thanks geekosaur, I succeeded in solving it using Perl's IMAPClient module. I will soon post my solution on my blog [sachintech.net](http://sachintech.net) and post the link here.